# How to check to see if any numbers or letters exist in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to check to see if a string has at least a letter OR number. What would be the best way to check that?

Comment: There are a million dups for this question. Why not perform a search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple regex:

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(some_string);
```

Comment: Clean and simple. Extract to a variable if you want to re-use the expression.

Comment: `/[A-Z0-9]/i.test(str)` slightly shorter

Comment: `/[0-9a-z]/i` would also be possible, just for the record.